# How to capture the port number in .HAR logs

Tags: google-chrome, http, web-developer-toolbar

I noticed Chrome doesn't capture the port number for Remote Addresses (called `serverIPAddress` in the json) in the .HAR log.

It shows port 80 when you open the .HAR file in Chrome even though the port was actually 443.

Is there any settings or something I can change to capture the port?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be a bug in chrome from not including the connection value.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334230

Comment: Do you mean the port number?

Comment: Yes but its key is called connection in a HAR file.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you look at the har trace in live you see 443 for the port, but once you save the har traces and reopened it, you see 80.
Certainly due to the fact that the port data is not stored when exported.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for your comment. Yeah it definitely seems like a bug. By the way, you can put comments like this which aren't direct answers to the question, as comments under the question itself, just FYI.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner Actually, Danial **can't** post a comment under the question - yet. One [needs 50 reputation for that privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AdrianMole What a strange feature. Thanks for letting me know.